# Can I run an eGPU on a Linux Partition of a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, partition, unix, gpu

I'm hoping to do some machine learning / tensorflow tasks with my eGPU, but after it arrived today, I realized that tensorflow discontinued support for Mac NVIDIA GPUs.

I'd like to install a Ubuntu partition and run the most recent tensorflow-gpu package on that. Would the eGPU still be supported in that case? Would any extra steps be needed to set it up in macOS before running it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3):

If you install Ubuntu as a dual boot arrangement, both operating systems run independent of each other. In other words, when booted to Ubuntu, the Mac preforms the same as any other PC. The only involvement with the macOS would be the need to create enough free space to allow Ubuntu to be installed.

Comment: is there a particular tutorial/guide you could recommend for this?

Comment: @Nic: What is the model/year of your Mac? What operating systems do you have installed?

Comment: I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016) running Mojave. I'm looking at installing Ubuntu on a USB stick. I figure once it's booted it shouldn't affect my TF performance.

Comment: @Nic: I do not have much experience running Ubuntu from a USB stick. Other than running a live version of Ubuntu.

Comment: I would like to use Debian and would Debian be able to access all the bandwidth of both the thunderbolt ports, say for external Nvidia GPU and additional monitors?

Comment: @NaveenKumar: What is the model/year of your Mac?

Comment: @DavidAnderson i have a 13-inch M1 mac from last year. one more question, will debian be able to access full CPU power? I plan to do this from bootcamp.

Comment: I do not think the M1 Macs are capable of installing Windows through the Boot Camp Assistant. I do not have access to any M1 Macs, so I do not know for sure. I think you are asking questions that are way beyond anything I can answer.

Comment: ok. i wanted to install debian from bootcamp, not windows. all i wanted to know was, if i would be able to utilise all the hardware from debian?